# Why Laravel Installer install faster?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

According to Laravel's documentation, it says "This method of installation (Laravel Installer) is much faster than installing via Composer".

My question is why & how it is much faster than Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from here [**`https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L97`**](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L97)

> it actually downloads a latest zip which is cached to serve faster
>   that's why it's fast. Also when you download you will see all the
>   packages are installed. So no package are individually installed
>   that's why it's more faster.

You can checkout more about the package source code **https://github.com/laravel/installer**